# Como passar dados de duas tabelas não relacionadas numa view?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou tentando passar para uma view, dados provenientes de duas tabelas não relacionadas. Aparecem apenas os dados de uma, os da outra, estão invisível, mas dá para perceber a alteração no layout quando esses dados são carregados. Outro facto que achei curioso, é que não está dando erro.

Para melhor percepção, aqui vai o código:

**Layout**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Controller.php**

```html
abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected function getLemas() {
        return Lema::where('status_lm', 'Activo')->get();
    }

    protected function getIgreja() {
        return Lema::All();
    }
}
```

**LemaController**

```html
public function create()
    {

        return view('lema.create-lema')->with('lema', $this->getLemas())->with('igreja',$this->getIgreja());
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $lema=new Lema();
        $lema->texto_lm = $request->texto;
        $lema->refBilblica_lm = $request->refBiblica;
        $lema->status_lm = $request->status;
        $lema->save();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

**IgrejaController**

```html
 public function create()
    {
        return view('igreja.create-igreja')->with('lema', $this->getLemas())->with('igreja',$this->getIgreja());
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('logo'))
        {
            $logo = $request->file('logo');
            $extensao = $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();

            if($extensao != 'jpg' && $extensao != 'jpeg' && $extensao != 'png')
            {
                return back()->with('erro','Erro: Este arquivo não é uma imagem JPG ou PNG');
            }
        }

        $igreja = new Igreja();
        $igreja->nome_ig = $request->nome;
        $igreja->missao_ig = $request->missao;
        $igreja->valores_ig = $request->valores;
        $igreja->visao_ig = $request->visao;
        $igreja->historial_ig = $request->historial;
        $igreja->endereco_ig = $request->endereco;
        $igreja->telefone_ig = $request->telefone;
        $igreja->telefone1_ig = $request->telefone1;
        $igreja->email_ig = $request->email;
        $igreja->logo_ig = "";
        $igreja->save();

        if(Input::file('logo'))
        {
            File::move($logo,public_path().'/imagem-logo/igreja-id_'.$igreja->id.'.'.$extensao);
            $igreja->logo_ig = '/imagem-logo/igreja-id_'.$igreja->id.'.'.$extensao;
            //$post->imagem = public_path().'/imagem-post/post-id_'.$post->id.'.'.$extensao;
            $igreja->save();
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

**HomeController**

```html
public function index()
    {

        return view('home')->with('lema', $this->getLemas())->with('igreja',$this->getIgreja());

    }
```

**Route**

```html
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('criar-lema', 'LemaController@store');
Route::get('criar-lema', 'LemaController@create');

Route::get('criar-igreja', 'IgrejaController@create');
Route::post('criar-igreja', 'IgrejaController@store');
```

**View banner.blade.php**

```html
<div class="page-header page-header-home">

    <div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 0px; background-color: #85B200">
        <?php foreach ($igreja as $key => $value): ?>
            <img src="{!! url ($value->logo_ig) !!}" alt="...">
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <a href="#"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="float: right; position: relative; margin-top: 100px; margin-right: 20px; color: #FFFFFF">Iniciar Sessão</i></a>
        <div style="padding: 2px; background-color: #4C6600; width: 450px; height: 90px; border-radius: 15px; position: relative; float: right; margin-right: 190px; margin-top: 22px">
            <?php foreach ($lema as $key => $value): ?>
            <p style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Tw Cen MT', Arial, 'Helvetica LT Std';font-size: 22px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 90%;">{!! $value->texto_lm  !!}</p>

            <p style="padding: 0px; text-align: center; font-family: 'Tw Cen MT', Arial, 'Helvetica LT Std';font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 90%;">{!! $value->refBilblica_lm  !!}</p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Por favor, preciso de ajuda, que desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Qual rota você está tentando acessar?

Comment: A primeira "Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');"

Comment: antes do return do seu método HomeController@index coloque dd( $this->getLemas()) e depois dd($this->getIgreja()), e coloque os resultados para gente poder ver o que está acontecendo

Comment: Apenas está me trazendo os dados de dd($this->getLemas()).

Comment: Tanto dd($this->getLemas()), como dd($this->getIgreja()), estão me retornando somente os dados da tabela "lemas".

Comment: Sim, pois $this->getLemas() está retornando os dados da tabela Lema onde 'status_lm' é igual à  'Activo' e o $this->getIgreja() está retornando todos os dados da tabela Lema, não é esse o comportamento que você deseja?

Comment: Não. O que desejo, é o  $this->getIgreja() retornar os dados da tabela "igreja", onde consta o logotipo que tem de aparecer no banner. E o $this->getLemas(), retorna os dados da tabela Lema onde 'status_lm' é igual à 'Activo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando rápido o seu código tanto o `getLemas()` quanto o `getIgreja()` estão buscando os dados de `Lemas`

```
protected function getLemas() {
    return Lema::where('status_lm', 'Activo')->get();
}

protected function getIgreja() {
    return Lema::All();
}
```

O `getIgreja()` não deveria estar:

```
protected function getIgreja() {
    return Igreja::all();
}
```

Como no `banner.blade.php` você está passando o valor para o `src` da imagem, aparentemente não dá erro e a imagem não carrega, pois ela é provavelmente renderizada como:

```
<?php foreach ($igreja as $key => $value): ?>
    <img src="{!! url ($value->logo_ig) !!}" alt="...">
<?php endforeach; ?>

//no html deve ficar algo como:
<img src="null" alt="...">
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!! Realmente a falha estava no protected function getIgreja() {
    return Lema::All();
}, quando deveria ser protected function getIgreja() {
    return Igreja::all();
}

Comment: @DanieldosSantos aproveitando eu te recomendo a utilizar a sintaxe do blade ao invés de códigos `<?php ?>`, assim tu poderia aproveitar os benefícios do framework e deixar teu código padronizado.
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

Comment: Obrigado @AndreGusmao!